# Symmetry and Coordinate invariance

Tags: symmetry, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames, poincare-symmetry, diffeomorphism-invariance

How are spacetime symmetries different from simple general coordinate invariance?
Physical laws should be coordinate independent. Are Poincare invariances not simply changing coordinates?

Comment: No, spacetime symmetries in the sense you're describing are physical symmetries (i.e. moving points of the manifold around, otherwise known as *isometries*), whereas coordinate invariance (or covariance) leaves the points unchanged. Writing a theory a generally covariant way says nothing about the isometries of the spacetime.

Comment: See also: active/passive transformations.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps it would be useful to consider a system which does *not* exhibit Poincare invariance.  A typical relativistic action for a worldline $\gamma$ in Minkowski space $\mathcal M$ might look like this:

$$S[\gamma] = \int d\sigma \left[mc^2\sqrt{\eta_{\gamma}(\dot \gamma,\dot \gamma)} - U(\gamma) \right]$$

where $\gamma=\gamma(\sigma)$ and $\eta_\gamma$ is the flat spacetime metric at the point $\gamma(\sigma)$.  This makes no reference to any coordinates, so it is manifestly coordinate-invariant.  It is **not** Poincare invariant, however.

A Poincare transformation is a diffeomorphism $\phi:\mathcal M \rightarrow \mathcal M$ which preserves the flat spacetime metric, i.e.

$$ \eta_{\phi(\gamma)}(\phi_*\dot \gamma,\phi_*\dot \gamma) = \eta(\dot \gamma,\dot \gamma)$$

where $\phi_*$ is the pushforward along $\phi$.  If you aren't familiar with that terminology, it simply means that when you map spacetime points to other spacetime points via $\phi$, you also map tangent vectors to other tangent vectors via $\phi_*$. Concretely, $\phi$ might implement a spatial rotation, a boost, or a spacetime translation on spacetime points, while $\phi_*$ implements the corresponding transformation on the tangent vectors.

The new action obtained after this transformation is

$$S[\phi\circ\gamma] = \int d\sigma\left[mc^2\sqrt{\eta_{\phi(\gamma)}(\phi_*\dot \gamma,\phi_*\dot \gamma)}-U\big(\phi(\gamma)\big)\right] $$
$$=\int d\sigma\left[mc^2\sqrt{\eta_\gamma(\dot \gamma,\dot \gamma)}-U\big(\phi(\gamma)\big)\right]$$

where we've used the fact that $\phi$ is an isometry of $\eta$.  Clearly this is not the same as the original action, because the second term has become $U\big(\phi(\gamma)\big)$.  As a result, Poincare invariance for a single particle in an external potential requires that the external potential be a constant function on spacetime - but that's the same as no external potential at all.

---

In more down-to-Earth terms, coordinate invariance is trivial because when we change coordinates $x^\mu\mapsto x'^\mu$, we *also* change the form of e.g. the potential function $U_{(x)}(\mathbf x)\mapsto U_{(x')}(\mathbf x')$, where the latter transformation is defined in such a way as to preserve the physics.  In Physics 101 we say the gravitational potential is $U(x,y)=mgy$; if we were to implement a 90$^\circ$ clockwise rotation, then this function would become $U'(x',y')=-mgx'$.  This is a **different function**, which is specifically chosen so that solutions of the old equations of motion are mapped to solutions of the new equations of motion under our 90$^\circ$ rotation.

A physical symmetry is very different.  It contains physical content because it asserts that when we change coordinates $x^\mu \mapsto x'^\mu$, solutions to the equations of motion are preserved even when we **don't** change $U$.  That is, $U$ is insensitive to the transformation we performed on the coordinates.  This requires very specific conditions on $U$ (which depend on the transformation in question, of course), and so the presence of a physical symmetry is a powerful constraint on what $U$ could be.

Answer (score 2):

There are two Poincare transformation that we can think about. The first is spacetime isometries and the other is change of observer. All of them is coordinate independent.

1. **Space time isometries**.
   I will consider $\textbf{spacetime}$  as $(M,\eta)$ where $M$ is a four dimensional $\textbf{manifold}$ and $g$ the metric which in this coordinates
   $$
   \begin{align*}
     x \colon M &\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^4\\
     p &\mapsto x(p)=(x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3).\tag 1
   \end{align*}
   $$
   is given by
   $$g^{(x)}=dx^0\otimes dx^0-dx^1\otimes dx^1-dx^2\otimes dx^2-dx^3\otimes dx^3 \tag2$$ Suppose we have the equation of motion for particle  given by $$\nabla_{v_\gamma}v_\gamma=F \tag3 $$ where $v_\gamma$ is the tangent vector associated with the curve $\gamma$ and $F$ is a force field.  Let $\phi:M\rightarrow M$ be a diffeomorphism, we define the induced metric by $$\widetilde{g}(X,Y)=g(\phi_*X,\phi_*Y) \tag 4$$.Associated with this metric we have the connection $\widetilde{\nabla}$ wich we can show that $\varphi_{*} \nabla_{X} Y=\widetilde{\nabla}_{\phi_{*} X}\left(\phi_{*} Y\right)$ and so we have $$ \widetilde{\nabla}_{\phi_*v_\gamma}\phi_*v_\gamma=\phi_*F  \tag 5 $$  So if $\gamma$ is a a solution of eq $(3)$ ,$\phi(\gamma$) is a solution of eq $(5)$ this is the meaning of the expression *diffeomorphism map solution into solution*. Now in special relativity the metric $g$ is not a dynamic variable that is ,it is fixed. So in $(4)$ we need that $\phi$ satisfy $$\widetilde{g}(X,Y)=g(\phi_*X,\phi_*Y)=g(X,Y) \tag 6$$ Diffeomorphism satisfying condition $(6)$  are called Poincare transformation. I hope the examples bellow illustrate the difference between coordinate transformation and diffeomorphism.

**Example 1**
Suppose we change from  coordinates $(1)$ to coordinates $$y_0=x_0, \quad y_1=x_1+x_2, \quad y_2=x_2, \quad y_3=x_3 \tag 7 $$ than $(2)$ becomes $$g^{(y)}=dx^0\otimes dy^0- \frac{1}{2}dy^1\otimes dy^1-\frac{1}{2}dy^2\otimes dy^2-dy^3\otimes dy^3 \tag8 $$
From $(1)$ we have that $g^{(x)}(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1},\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1})=-1$. In coordinates $(7)$ we have $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial}{\partial y_1}+\frac{\partial}{\partial y_2}$ and so using $(8)$ we have that $g^{(y)}(\frac{\partial}{\partial y_1}+\frac{\partial}{\partial y_2},\frac{\partial}{\partial y_1}+\frac{\partial}{\partial y_2})=-1$

Now suppose that we have a diffeomorphism given in coordinates $(1)$ by   $$x_0 \rightarrow x_0, \quad x_1\rightarrow x_1+x_2, \quad x_2 \rightarrow x_2, \quad x_3\rightarrow x_3 \tag 9 $$
Under this diffeomorphism we have that $ \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\rightarrow\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}+\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}$ and since the metric is fixed we have from $(2)$ that
$g^{(x)}(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}+\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2},\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}+\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2})=-2$

As we see in this example for coordinates transformation the result remain invariant while for diffeomorphism it changed.

**Example 2**. Suppose we use cylindrical coordinates $(t,r,\theta,z)$ whose coordinates transformation from $2$ are given by $$x_0=t,\quad x_1= r\cos \theta ,\quad x_2= r\sin \theta, \quad x_3=z $$Now suppose we have the  diffeomorphism  $$t \rightarrow \gamma(t-vr \cos \theta), \quad r \rightarrow \sqrt{\gamma^2(r \cos \theta -vt)^2 +r^2 \sin^2 \theta},\\ \theta \rightarrow  \tan ^{-1}(\frac{r \sin \theta}{\gamma(r \cos \theta -vt)}),  \quad  z\rightarrow z \\ \tag 9$$
In this coordinates we can show that $$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\rightarrow \gamma \cos \theta \frac{\partial}{\partial r}+\gamma\frac{\sin \theta }{ r}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} + \gamma v \frac{\partial}{\partial r}\tag 10$$

In cylindrical coordinates we can show that the metric $g$ is given by
$$g^{(c)}=dt\otimes dt-dr\otimes dr-r^2d\theta\otimes d\theta-dz\otimes dz \tag11 $$
From $(10)$ and $(11)$ we can se that the $g(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1},\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1})$ is invariant under diffeomorphism $(9)$
Diffeomorphism $(9)$ is called **Lorentz transformation**

2. **Change of observers**. An $\textbf{observer}$ is a worldline $\gamma$ with together with a choice of basis
   $
   O=v_{\gamma,\gamma(\lambda)} \equiv e_0(\lambda) , e_1(\lambda), e_2(\lambda), e_3(\lambda)
   $
   of each $T_{\gamma(\lambda)}M$ where the observer worldline passes, if
   $$
   g(e_a(\lambda), e_b(\lambda)) = \eta_{ab} = \left[ \begin{matrix} 1 & & & \\ & -1 & & \\ & & -1 & \\ & & & -1 \end{matrix} \right]_{ab} \tag2
   $$

$v_{\gamma,\gamma(\lambda)}$  is the tangent vector of the the curve $\gamma$ at the point $\gamma(\lambda)$.
Suppose we have two *inertial observer* $\gamma^A(\lambda)$ and $\gamma^B(\lambda)$.In coordinates $(1)$ we have $x^\mu(\gamma^A)=(\lambda,0,0,0)$ and $x^\mu(\gamma^B)=(\Lambda^0_0\lambda+q^0,\Lambda^1_0\lambda+q^1,\Lambda^2_0\lambda+q^2,\Lambda^3_0\lambda+q^3)$.Suppose also that $e^A_0=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^0},\quad e^A_1=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^1},\quad e^A_2=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^2},\quad e^A_3=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^3}$.We can show that $e^B_{\mu}=\Lambda^\nu_\mu e_{\nu}$ with $$\eta_{ab}=\Lambda^\nu_a\Lambda^\mu_b\eta_{\nu \mu}$$. Let $\phi$ be a map that take us from observer $A$ to observer $B$ that is $\phi(\gamma^A)=\gamma^B$ . Than we have $$\phi_*\Bigg(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^0}\Bigg)=\frac{\partial \phi^\nu}{\partial x^0}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\nu}=\Lambda^\nu_0\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\nu}$$ if we impose additionally that $\frac{\partial \phi^\nu}{\partial x^\mu}=\Lambda^\nu_\mu$ we would have the solution $$\phi^\nu=\Lambda^\nu_\mu x^\mu+q^\nu$$
The last expression has this format in the coordinates $(1)$ .Of course if we choose another coordinate it would have another format.